# Image does not display using Picasso in android

Tags: android, retrofit, picasso

I have this problem when fetching image using the Picasso dependency. But when I fetch other strings they are displayed on my android app.Here are my codes:

ListAdapter.java

```
 public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_list,parent,false);
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.type = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.name.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        holder.type.setText(getItem(position).getType());
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(getItem(position).getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView name;
        TextView type;
    }
}
```

When I changed the getItem(position).getThumbnail() to "http://some_image_here.png" I can see the picture.

Restaurant.java

```
 public class Restaurant implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String description;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String image;

    public Restaurant(){

    }
    public Restaurant(String name, String type, String description, String thumbnail, String image){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.description = description;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.image = image;
    }
    public  Restaurant(Parcel source){
        name = source.readString();
        type = source.readString();
        description = source.readString();
        thumbnail = source.readString();
        image = source.readString();
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {

        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getDescription() {

        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {

        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        applyDefaultValues();

        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(type);
        dest.writeString(description);
        dest.writeString(image);
        dest.writeString(thumbnail);
    }

    private void applyDefaultValues() {
        if(name == null)
            name="";
        if(type == null)
            type ="";
        if(description == null)
            description = "";
        if(image == null)
            image = "";
        if(thumbnail == null)
            thumbnail = "";
    }
    public static Creator<Restaurant>CREATOR = new Creator<Restaurant>() {
        @Override
        public Restaurant createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

            return new Restaurant(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Restaurant[] newArray(int size) {

            return new Restaurant[size];
        }
    };
}
```

And here are my codes for fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.findmerest.fragment.ListRestFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong in my code?

I include the ListRestFragment:

```
public class ListRestFragment extends ListFragment {

private ListAdapter mAdapter;
public static ListRestFragment getInstance(){
    ListRestFragment fragment = new ListRestFragment();
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setListShown(false);
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),0);

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(getString(R.string.restaurant_list))
            .build();
    RestaurantApiInterface restaurantApiInterface = adapter.create(RestaurantApiInterface.class);
    restaurantApiInterface.getStreams(new Callback<List<Restaurant>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Restaurant> restaurants, Response response) {
            if (restaurants == null || restaurants.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            for (Restaurant restaurant : restaurants) {
                mAdapter.add(restaurant);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            setListShown(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("Restaurant", "error" + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ListRestDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ListRestDetailActivity.EXTRA_RESTAURANT,mAdapter.getItem(position));

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

restaurant list:

```
 <string name="restaurant_list">https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jayGorio/23fed06b792dd59ccc60/raw/ba7e3943c01703f032692b363088be519e022399</string>
```

Comment: *When I changed the getItem(position).getThumbnail() to "http://some_image_here.png" I can see the picture.* Then `getItem(position).getThumbnail()` is returning an invalid url

Comment: @Arthur Korchagin Thanks for the edit. Can you offer some solution to my problem?

Comment: as Blackbelt said above, getThumbnail is returning an invalid URL, you should debug that and find out what getThumbnail is returning..

Comment: @Cata i doesnt return any debug message for the url.

Comment: Well then it seems that the item you are trying to use has invalid data.. also make sure that when you implement the read and write methods in the parcelable, you are keping the order of the elements so in both methods you have to read and write them in the same order.. you switched the thumbnail with the image, I am not sure if that is the cause of your problem or not

Comment: @Cata But Im using the same url for the image.I already changed the order but then again same error.

Comment: Ok then you should give us more info, I don't know where are you implementing the getItem method or how do you send your data to the adapter.. you should make sure you indeed see data in your objects before passing it to the adapter

Comment: @Cata I included ListRestFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
       .load(new File(getItem(position).getThumbnail()))
       .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

Comment: I got this error: 12-02 22:57:04.334  16665-16665/com.findmerest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
            at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
            at com.findmerest.adapter.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:44)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)

Comment: try to print it as.. `Log.e("ImageUrl",getItem(position).getThumbnail());` and see the logs in red color what is the vallue of ImageUrl prints.

Comment: and the problem is that... you are getting null. check the data you received.

Comment: I displayed using Log It doesnt display anything i t seems theres wrong with the link..But how come when I use the url directly as parameter to the load it is working.But when I used getItem(position).getThumbnail it's not working..Can someone please offer suggestions.

Comment: your `getItem(position).getThumbnail()` returns null. check where you are setting data to the list. It is null.

Comment: Thanks for all your help yaeh its returning invalid url. I change the url and now its working..

Answer (score -1):

Just Use Log.d("ImageUrl",getItem(position).getThumbnail().toString()) and see the Log to get If it is returning valid or invalid URL.

:D

Comment: It does not display whether the url is valid. But it returns error when i click on the page.